# PDF Viewer for Windows 8.1 app

Tags: windows, winrt-xaml

Im trying to implement a pdf viewer for Win 8.1 app using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532207.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.

I need search text feature using this. I know Reader for Windows 8 does it, but i dont know how.

Can anyone help me please!

Thx!

Comment: Component one has a control that does this http://www.componentone.com/Studio/Reporting-Documents/PdfViewerWinRT

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for advice. I used it but the render mode is not with images and it decrase performance a lot when searching. I want to know how to implement search with images render mode like Lector app does.

Comment: Could you detail your question or check an answer?

Answer (score 0):

check this great blog post with a summary of available components for WinRT.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulwhit/archive/2013/02/15/pdf-view-components-for-windows-store-apps-winrt-xaml-c.aspx
You might check each component vendor specs as some have been enhanced since the time the article was written (ex : DevExpress PDF component for UWP supports search) BuiltIn PDF component purpose is to render documents, not manipulate. You can contact the dev team for feature requests.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/pdf_api_blog/